# HttpFormUrlEncodedContent object but without encoding the paremeters

Tags: c#, post, asynchronous, httprequest, httpclient

I'm using the `HttpFormUrlEncodedContent` object in my application for a `PostAsync` method of `Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient`, and I have it set like so:

```
HttpFormUrlEncodedContent httpFormUrlEncodedContent = new HttpFormUrlEncodedContent(new[] {
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("parameterOne", "value of one"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("parameterTwo", "value of two"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("parameterThree", "value of three"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("scope", "FIRST_PARAMETER+SECOND_PARAMETER+THIRD_PARAMETER")
});

HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
response = await httpClient.PostAsync("http://mysuperdupperurl.com", httpFormUrlEncodedContent);
```

My problem with this is that the scope is encoded, and when it gets to the server throws an error, because encoded looks like this:

```
FIRST_PARAMETER%2BSECOND_PARAMETER%2BTHIRD_PARAMETER
```

So, is there some kind of `HttpFormUrlUnencodedContent` or some other way of defining the content of my `PostAsync` method?